# Managing View Controllers in iPad port

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I've got an app that I've developed for the iPhone, but now want to port to the iPad. The iPhone app is navigation style and based on discrete table view controllers managed by a nav controller. The larger screen real estate of the iPad means that I can comfortably fit a couple of these table view controllers on to the screen at the same time.

The question is how? Should I

a) have the main view load two table view controllers from separate NIBs and then position them on screen (I'm not sure how I set they x and y of subviews loaded from nibs).

b) create sub-views in my main nib and populate these with data from my existing classes (if so how do I hook up the IBOutlets)?

c) do something completely different

One thing I should point out is that I don't want to use the split screen option.

Comment: The question is quite confusing, but you should keep in the the Apple HIG and why they were created. The consistency of the UI in Apple Products are what make the iOS application eco-system easy to adpot for its customers. If you create a UI that is inconsistent with how a user would expect an Apple product to function, it could negatively impact the perception of you application

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I'm not trying to do anything that would be counter-intuitive from a HIG perspective, it's just that the iPad opens more scope for creating unique user interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now trivial to do this sort of thing with container views in iOS, which is why Apple added container views:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25910881/294884

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884

---

Historic answer ... use a chain of subviews.

Comment: Thanks. I guessed that there must be a solution of this sort, but I was struggling to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear on the right way to implement this. The main view controller has IBOutlets for each of the 'baskets' and its this IBOutlet connection to the subview that I'm calling. Each of the view controllers that I'm going to show in each basket has it's own nib and associated IBOutlets. Right?

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for the excellent answer. I may not have been very clear in my question but you understood what I was getting at. I've got it compiling OK, but my baskets are showing up empty, i.e. they're not showing the views of the view controllers that I've imported. When you've use this technique, do you simply include the headers of the imported files in your main view controller, or do you forward class them in some way?

Comment: Joe, Many thanks again. You're right I wasn't instantiating it.